# Signalr connection state between two android activities

Tags: connection, signalr

Now i'm try to developing android and multi client live chat application usin signalr. But i got a problem with signalr connection state. One thing is I don't know how to keep connection state between two android activities. Second is, I don't know how to keep signalr connection state in android. I tried to disconnect signalr connection state when android activity destroy, that's is ok but i got problem when user clean recent application from OS my android client is try to connect new connection oncreate. That's why i want to know how to keep Signalr connection state between android two activity and how to keep signalr connection state.

Another thing is should i use signalr for android instant messaging application. Because i want to create instant messaging application using signalr.

Thanks.